# how to make html static page generator using php

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I am creating a website for a company and they want in the admin panel to be a page creator to add webpage on the website if they want and I create all the admin panel except this need any help in how to make the admin panel can create a web page in the website and if anyone had idea tell it to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they want is a Content Management System (CMS). Search online for CMS and once you have a CMS, you can implement the design/layout you are building for their web site into the CMS.

You can build your own CMS, but that is a big task. That would involve storing the data/content of the web site into a database. When a web visitor visits the web page, it is a PHP page (with HTML template/design, but no content) and that PHP page will retrieve the necessary data/content from the database and fill it into the template and then output the template with the data to the web visitor.

On the control panel side, you would need to allow your clients to edit the data in the database, altering the data/content that will fill into the templates when web visitors visit the site. The database will also need to store the structure of the entire web site (ie. navigation, etc). Furthermore, you would need a place for your clients to upload images and your PHP code will need to process the image and store in a folder somewhere and then store the reference to the image in the database. Furthermore, you will need some kind of user management system.

As you can see, it is a big task to program a CMS by yourself.

I would suggest start by finding a CMS online that you can install and customize that will fit your client needs and/or template/design. Most CMS will run off of PHP+MySQL.

Good luck!

Comment: i want thank you bro i create a cms but with small features like  edit posts and users and new and some others thank you can you tell me a good cms but without copyright on it and open source so if i want to edit it or add it

Comment: So to support the creation of web pages in the current CMS you built, you will need to store the data of each page and the template of each page in your database. You can create several templates for different types of pages. So when a visitor visits index.php, the page will retrieve the home page data with the template you have designated for that page. Links to an "about us" page will be like index.php?page=2 or something similar to that. When the script sees the page in the parameter, it will grab the data and template indicated in the database for that page.

Comment: So when your clients create a new page, they will add a page to the database and select the template to use.

Comment: As for CMS, there are many good open source ones to choose from. If you search online, you can find CMS comparisons and go from there.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but I know of many big web development companies that use that CMS.